# Win 8.1 restarts wpf application when connecting via Remote Desktop Connection

Tags: c#, wpf, remote-desktop

I have a WPF application, I start running my app on my computer (running win 8.1), then when I try to connect from a remote machine (running win 7) my app crashes.
From debugging I found out that all my user controls are being constructed from the start. Since I have resources and files held by the "old" objects I get an exception, also I don’t want my app to start from the beginning because most likely it’s in a middle of a task.

Does anyone know why this happens?

-If I connect to my computer and then run my app, there is no problem. 
-There is no problem if connecting with remote connection from win7 to win7

Thanks

Comment: Can you add some details to "it crashes"? What exactly is happening? What exception?

Comment: When you connect with remote desktop, the entire visual tree for your application is reconstructed - causing new objects for visual elements to be created.  I believe this is being caused by the WPF rendering mode changing from hardware to software.  Try forcing the app to only run in software rendering mode and see if the reoccurs

Comment: @thorkia the problem reoccures also when changing rendering mode to software. it seems this is only a problem in win8.1 because the visual objects don't reconstruct when remoting to win7

Comment: @nvoigt the problem is the visual objects are reconstructed and the "old" ones still have resources and files open. when the "new" objects construct they try to open the same files and get access denied exception.